# We don't call it homesick. We call it missing home. There's not a sickness involved, it's a state of mind. Is this correct?

Tags: word-meaning

> We don't call it homesick. We call it missing home. There's not a sickness involved; it's a state of mind.

Is this saying correct?

Comment: Hi Maria your question needs more context and explanation about what you need to know.

Comment: i want to ask if the sentence is ok . is there any complicated words?

Comment: and also what is the xplanation of the sentence ?

Comment: What are you asking about? Are you asking why we say "**home sick**" instead of just saying that someone misses his or her home?

Comment: its all about homesick

Comment: The reason why no one has answered to your question yet is because the question was poorly written and elaborated. I can't answer to your question without understanding it. You will have to edit your question and post it again.

Answer (score 3):

> Homesickness is a state of emotional distress that people sometimes experience when they are separated from supportive friends or family members in an unfamiliar environment. … Homesickness probably evolved to discourage people from leaving supportive groups when our prehistoric ancestors lived in small nomadic bands and rarely moved from one band to another.  (["The Science of Homesickness"](http://dukemagazine.duke.edu/article/the-science-of-homesickness))

**If you're asking about the suitability of the sentence...**

> We don't call it homesick. We call it missing home. There's not a sickness involved,it's a state of mind.

**Factually** it's correct.  There isn't an *illness,* meaning there is no breakdown of the human body due to bacteria, virus, fungus, etc.  "Homesickness" is a word that describes a state of being or a state of the mind.

**Grammatically** it's not how I'd say it, but without more context I don't know *why* you're using the sentences.  Here in my portion of the U.S., we call it "homesickness," so without knowing the *reason* behind your use of those sentences I can't explain whether they make sense or not (as written and without context, the first two sentences are incorrect because, here, we do call it "homesickness").

*If you were trying to assert the claim that homesickness is a mental issue, not a physical issue, the phrases might be better said: "We call it homesickness, but it isn't a physical illness.  It's a state of mind."*

**Contextually** the statements can be incorrect.  While "homesickness" isn't a disease or a breakdown due to bacteria, virus, fungus, etc., it is a form of *mental illness* in that the body cannot perform optimally due to conditions caused by the *mental illness.*  Whether it's [homesickness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homesick), [lovesickness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lovesick), depression, fear, or panic, the *mental condition* can be physically debilitating — meaning the *consequence* is similar to physical forms of illness.  Therefore, contextually the statements can be legitimately thought of as wrong.

*Which of the three above matters most depends on why you are using these sentences, which you have not provided.*